# How to graph TF-IDF feature vs Logistic Regression?

Tags: python, numpy, graph, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am running a logistic regression on a single column, which is text on which I am using TF-IDF. I wish to plot my Logistic regression on a graph so I can see if it is underfitting or overfitting and just to get a nice visualisation of the data. How can I **graph** this in order to visualise my data effectively? MSE on the Y axis, and what on the X axis? What can be graphed from a TF-IDF? How can I do this?

Here is my code :

```
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  from sklearn import metrics,preprocessing,cross_validation
  from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
  import sklearn.linear_model as lm
  import pandas as p
  loadData = lambda f: np.genfromtxt(open(f,'r'), delimiter=' ')
  traindata = list(np.array(p.read_table('train.tsv'))[:,2])
  testdata = list(np.array(p.read_table('test.tsv'))[:,2])
  y = np.array(p.read_table('train.tsv'))[:,-1]

  tfv = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=3,  max_features=None, strip_accents='unicode',  
        analyzer='word',token_pattern=r'\w{1,}',ngram_range=(1, 2), use_idf=1,smooth_idf=1,sublinear_tf=1)

  rd = lm.LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', dual=True, tol=0.0001, 
                             C=1, fit_intercept=True, intercept_scaling=1.0, 
                             class_weight=None, random_state=None)

  X_all = traindata + testdata
  lentrain = len(traindata)
  print "fitting pipeline"
  tfv.fit(X_all)
  print "transforming data"
  X_all = tfv.transform(X_all)

  X = X_all[:lentrain]
  X_test = X_all[lentrain:]

  print "training on full data"
  rd.fit(X,y)
```

My data is 27 columns, 7000 rows.

How can I effectively visualise my data to see if underfitting or overfitting is occuring? What can I put on the X axis here?

I'd essentially like some code as follows, but using TF-IDF and Logistic Regression rather than linear :

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
estimator = LinearRegression()
estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predicted = estimator.predict(X_test)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.xlabel("Feature")
plt.ylabel("MSE")
plt.ylim(-4, 14)
plt.scatter(X_train.ravel(), y_train, color = 'green')
plt.plot(X_test.ravel(), y_predicted, color = 'blue')
plt.show()
```

Which would display :

[image: Linear Regression on a graph to check for under and overfitting.]

What can I graph here, and how can I do it, in order to get the same feel for my data?

Thanks very much.

Comment: MSE on class labels makes very little sense.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics and plotting, not programming.